# Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials

Tags: api, reactjs, fetch-api

I want to get a JSON from an API in React.js. I'm tried with axios, superagent and fetch but it's doesn't worked?

```
let token = '****';
    let url = 'https://'+ token +'@api.navitia.io/v1/coverage/fr-idf/stop_areas/stop_area%3AOIF%3ASA%3A59491/departures?';

    let myInit = {
        'method': 'GET'
    }

    fetch(url, myInit).then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }).then((data)=> {
        console.log('ok');
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log('Erreur: ' + err);
    });
```

Error: "Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials"

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is letting you know the problem is it doesnt accept credentials in that manner.

You need to create a X-Auth-Token header and add the token to that. then pass the whole thing

Answer (score -2):

Try this changes

```
let myInit = {
    'method': 'GET',
    credentials: 'include' // or 'same-origin'
}
```